# How do I pass int values from one method to another

Tags: java, arrays, loops, return-value, min

I'm trying to find the lowest time in minutes of the array int [] times, but I can't figure out how to make the second method work; I'm not getting any output.

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    String[] names = { "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil",
            "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James", "Emily", "Daniel",
            "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };
    int[] times = { 321, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412,
            393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        System.out.println(names[i] + ":" + times[i]);
}
```

I don't know what it's missing but i know i should get the lowest time in minutes: which is 243 (int [] times). I "believe" i need to pass the int time values from the first method to the second method...since i feel the second method array is empty. However, that, i don't know how to do. Help?

```
public static int getMinIndex(int[] values) {
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        if (values[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = values[i];
            minIndex = i;
        }
    return minIndex; //not returning anything. 
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the method?

Comment: you don't seem to be calling your getMinIndex method from within your main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your program is:
1. Declaring an array of names.
2. Declaring an array of times.
3. Writing the names and times through a loop to the console.

You also wrote a method to retrieve the minimum value within an int array,
but you did not include that in your program, which starts from the first line of the main method.

So the first question would be, where would you like to use the minimum value.
and the second question would be, what would you like to do with the minimum value.

Suppose you want to show the min value on the console,
simply write:

```
System.out.println(getMinValue(times));
```

This way the method's return value is passed to the static method of System.out as an argument, suppose you want to do something else, pass it to another method that accepts int arrays.

Comment: I wrote `getMinValue`, OP wrote `getMinIndex`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but I didn't see your post before I made mine, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you for taking the time and answering it. It helped! I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your main method

```
int min_index = getMinIndex(times);
```

You forget to call method. Here `min_index` contains the integer value that you have to return from the method.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you really want a `getMinValue(int... arr)`

```
public static int getMinValue(int... values) {
  // Handle null and the empty array
  if (values == null || values.length < 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  // start at the first element
  int minValue = values[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] < minValue) {
      minValue = values[i];
    }
  }
  // return the minimum value
  return minValue;
}
```

Then you would call it with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(getMinValue(4, 0, 2, 3));
  int[] arr = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2 };
  System.out.println(getMinValue(arr));
}
```

Output is

```
0
2
```